# Joining lists that are values of dictionaries when repeated key exists

Tags: python, dictionary

Maybe this question has been asked but I am unable to find a feasible answer for my case.

I have 2 lists:

```
list1=['a','b','a']
list2=[['str1','str2','str3'],['str4','str5','str5'],   ['str4','str6','str6']]
```

I am looping over the list to generate a dictionary:

```
superdict={}
littledict={}
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if bool(superdict) == False:
        superdict[list1[i]]=list2[i]
    elif bool(superdict) == True:
         littledict[list1[i]]=list2[i]
         superdict.update(littledict)
```

However given that I have a repeated key in one of the dictionaries.
how could I join the values of the sublist3 from list2 into key 'a'

I was thinking in adding an

```
if littledict[list1[i]] in superdict:
    do something
```

the desired output:

```
{'a':['str1','str2','str3','str4','str6','str6'],'b':['str4','str5','str5']}
```

How could I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
list1=['a','b','a']
list2=[['str1','str2','str3'],['str4','str5','str5'],   ['str4','str6','str6']]
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
   d[a].extend(b)

print(dict(d))
```

Output:

```
{'a': ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', 'str6', 'str6'], 'b': ['str4', 'str5', 'str5']}
```

Answer (score 0):

- on top of my head you can just check if `key` is present in the `dict` or not.

```
list1=['a','b','a']
list2=[['str1','str2','str3'],['str4','str5','str5'],   ['str4','str6','str6']]
d = dict()
for k,v in zip(list1, list2):
    if k not in d:
        d[k] = []
    d[k].extends(v)
```

PS: or use `defaultdict`